# Add JavaScript code to View dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some code to display a google map. In my controller, I create the javascript:

```
MapCode = string.Format("<script type='text/javascript'>init_map('my_map', {0}, {1}, 20)</script>", location.Location.Coordinate.Latitude, location.Location.Coordinate.Longitude)
```

But I can't just write that to my view:

@Model.MapCode

Because that just displays the actual javascript - doesn't execute it.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass `location.Location` as the model and then do this on your view:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>init_map('my_map', '@Model.Coordinate.Latitude', '@Model.Coordinate.Longitude', 20)</script>
```

In that manner you don't have to build your script from the controller, which is always not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`HtmlHelper.Raw()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) to output raw HTML without encoding to the view.

```
@Html.Raw(Model.MapCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see mixing server-side and client-side (JavaScript and C#) code as a good practice.

Alternative you can use [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) if you are using jQuery. That way you can
create AJAX request to get data and do that in AJAX callback.